# Error handling custom REST activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I created a journey builder custom REST activity as described here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-rest-activity.htm

The execute arguments give you the chance to at least add retry and timeout. But what about 404 or 500 errors? Currently the activity just continues in the flow.

In addition is the REST activity also logging into any view or dataextension? I would expect or need sth. like SendLogs for Email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the retry will work for any errors (including 404 and 500), don't they? As it is a custom activity handling errors inside your activity's backend and logging to a data extension needs to be done by yourself. The only logging that occurs automatically is the data added to the Journey History.

**Related documentation:**

- [Journey History](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/journey_builder_administration/contact_administration/)
- [Create Custom Activities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)

Comment: Well retries only help for connection issues. If the backend URL is configured wrong or the backend is down 3 retries will not help. Of course I would like to handle errors within my custom activity but I do not see any configuration option like a "callback" or "onError" attribute. The only option i see is to use "contactUpdate" after the custom activity, read an expected outArgument like "status" and to update a data extension. Then afterwards you can do a decision split. If status success this way otherwise that way. But this would be a lot of overhead.

Comment: And concerning the logging.

Comment: I'm afraid Salesforce currently doesn't provide any other ways for error handling especially none for configuration or uptime issues on your end.

Comment: But as we are not living in a perfect world, it would be good to have at least the requests logged somewhere. Same as already done for SMS and Email. Otherwise it is a pretty useless blackbox feature without having any chance to monitor and do operational work.

Comment: You are right, however my answer is too, as currently there is no such functionality. So please mark it as accepted and if you wish to have the error handling capabilities for custom activities improved create an idea on [IdeaExchange in the Salesforce Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?filter=Marketing+Cloud).